# VB: Global array 'declaration expected'

Tags: vb.net

```
Module GlobalConstants
    Public strCDRack(0 To 2, 0 To 1) As String
        strCDRack(0, 0) = "Deftones"
        strCDRack(0, 1) = "Tool"
        strCDRack(0, 2) = "Disturbed"

        strCDRack(0, 0) = "Sticky Fingers"
        strCDRack(0, 1) = "Beggars Banquet"
        strCDRack(0, 2) = "Let It Bleed"


End Module
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBox1.Text = strCDRack(0, 1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I want to make a global array where all the buttons can access it. But im not sure how to do this?

Comment: you need to initialize that thing in a code block, and you can declare it in a form rather than module for all the buttons to get at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1
    Friend strCDRack(0 To 2, 0 To 1) As String   ' just declaring

    ' the error message `declaration expected` is telling you all that
    ' can be done at this level is to declare variables

    Sub Form Load...
        ' code to initialize the array or DO anything
        ' must be in a procedure
        strCDRack(0, 0) = "Deftones"
        strCDRack(1, 0) = "Tool"
        strCDRack(2, 0) = "Disturbed"

        strCDRack(0, 1) = "Sticky Fingers"
        strCDRack(1, 1) = "Beggars Banquet"
        strCDRack(2, 1) = "Let It Bleed"
```

You also messed up the indicies for the text.  You declared the array `(0 To 2, 0 To 1)` but then used only (0) for the first and went outside the bounds for the second dimension (0, 1, **2**).

See [Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/fJpjfLF0 clicking the button doesnt make textbox1 display anything?? Sorry really new at this..

Comment: If `TextBox1` is on form1 and it is your only form; or is the Startup form, it should work.  But you also messed up where the data is stored - see Edit.